# ruby on rails- Order results by two columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i've got an article table (model Article) that i want to order by two boolean columns (:foreground, :on_evidence) for show some results in a view

in the controller of the view in the action index:

```
class ShowController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @articles = Article.where("published = true ").order('foreground, on_evidence')
  end
end
```

this method is wrong...how can i do for this trouble?

Answer (score 0):

Ok i've found the solution simply i've changed the find query:

```
class ShowController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @articles = Article.where('published = true').order(foreground: :desc)
  end
end
```

Comment: In queries filtering must be before ordering for best performance. And You didn't solved your problem, just remove one column from order. What's wrong in your first version (in question)?

Comment: the results weren't ordered

Comment: @user3125036 actually, the order of `where` and `order` is **not** significant in ActiveRecord queries (this has absolutely **no** impact on performance). However, since the resulting SQL puts `where`s first and `order`s in the end, it makes sense to make calls in the same order.

Comment: @D-side, thanks for information, didn't know about that.
@user3125036, may be your data is not sortable by multiple columns? Eg ```foreground``` column has no same values, and You not saw ```on_evidence``` ordering? I tried sort my data as in your question, and it works.